# A good read for Xmas holidays!

Tags: sound-design, books, sound-effects

Fellow sound designers and foley artists!

Its Cristmas time! Fortunately all of you will have some free time these days (i dont unfortunately), so what a better idea to have some structural and educational read in this extra time?

My first and favourite is The Sound Effects Bible by master Ric Viers. It opened new horizons and ideas in this field for me. What i try to read now is the book Sound Design The expressive power of music, voice, and sound effects in Cinema, by David Sonnenschein.

I think this last one is THE BOOK in sound design. I will not tell you how to re-record lighsabers but it will tell you WHY you have to record anything... it delves more into the phychoacoustics part and the human psychology and the "storytelling" part of sound design and editing!

I am excited and i thought it should be good to share the knowledge!

Cheers and happy holidays!

Comment: I can't help recommending this thread http://socialsounddesign.com/questions/1945/audio-postproduction-sound-design-resources-youd-recommend that could be the one and only goto place for the ones of us in search of reading material. Also it'd be amazing that you contribute to describing the books that you know ;)

Answer (score 1):

I have both books, finished The sound effects Bible and working on Sound Design. Great reads and very inspirational. Ric Viers has some videos on designingsound.org tv where he interviews sound designers/recordists. Really good information.